# Using git "inside" or "outside" virtual machine?

Tags: git, vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm about to start a project with new coworkers and we're trying to find the best way to set up our work environnements.

We're using Vagrant and Virtual Box to work on the same environnement and about git, we were wondering if it was best to install git inside the VM and push commits from here or simply use git on our local OS in the Vagrant shared folders.

What do you guys usually do when working on a team?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Each developer can do what they like. there is literally no difference.

Comment: I use git wherever I need to edit the files.

Comment: When i do web development i follow the second approach, the folder containing the Vagrantfile, and a subfolder with the wwwroot with the stuff i'm working on (that will be loaded as shared forlder by vagrant), will be the root of the git repo for the project. Everyone will use the same vm configuration that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pretty much always use Git outside of the virtual machine. That way, there is no important state within the VM, and I can throw it away and rebuild it, or revert to a snapshot, or something of the sort, without worrying about losing any unpushed state, stashes, uncommitted files, and the like.

Comment: Thanks this is what I thought first. I guess we'll start on the host system and adapt if we feel there is a need to it.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but when the `.git` folder is located in the `/vagrant` folder - or whatever shared folder with  the host os, then no state is saved in the vm. Only the git binaries are installed in the vm in addition to the host os.

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, when you are using a shared folder, the `.git` directory is located on the host. However, shared folders don't actually support everything that you need; in particular, you can't create symlinks from within the guest in a shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think both is useful, having git on the host os and in the the vm. Having it on the host os allows to use git without need to enter the vm, having it in the vm allows to use git without leaving the vm (if you are currently working there)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would be working locally with vagrant.  So you must have git on the local machine.

The git repository will be in the shared folder.  If you install git on the VM any of your commits made to the shared folder mounts will be visible to the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice now for git is to have one main repository (usually called **origin**) hosted on the web by GitHub, BitBucket or any other service.

At the same time you can host a repository anywhere you want - inside VM, outside VM, on a host machine of your coworker and so on if you prefer and consider it as a better way for some reason.

Every environment that should read or write files in the repository usually has to have it's own local copy.

So it's really no matter about using VM for your purposes.

The only thing with shared folders - be aware of file access rules. If your setup could not provide enough access for file system modifications - git could fail to work properly.